# Why using SQLITE where clause does not work?

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I am trying to create a SQLITE query like this (first approach):

```
        int count;
        using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) )
            {
            count = ( from p in db.Table<TickRecord>()
                      where (p.TickStartDate.LocalDateTime >= start && p.TickEndtDate.LocalDateTime <= end )
                      select (int)p.DurationInSeconds ).Sum();
            }
        return count;
```

When running the query the application crash on the where clause.

I was able to achieve it like this (second approach):

```
        ObservableCollection<TickRecord> records;

        // Create a new connection
        using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) )
           {
           records = new ObservableCollection<TickRecord>( db.Table<TickRecord>().Select( i => i ) );
           }

        int count = records.Where( record => record.TickStartDate.LocalDateTime >= start && record.TickEndDate.LocalDateTime <= end ).Sum( record => record.DurationInSeconds );
```

Is there a way to achieve the same using my first approach?

Thx

Comment: What exception did you receive?

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in SQLite.Net.dll
Member access failed to compile expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the member access **'.LocalDateTime'** within your query.
The Linq processor is not able to convert '.LocalDateTime' into a sqlite query, simple because there is no equivalent function in sqlite.

As a result is throws an exception as you sad:

> [...] member access failed [...].

If you need the functionality of **'.LocalDateTime'**, then you should try to get all entries of the table from your database and use the where query later on, if you have already received all data.

```
int count;
using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) )
{
    var results = db.Table<TickRecord>().ToList();
    count = ( from p in results
              where (p.TickStartDate.LocalDateTime >= start && p.TickEndtDate.LocalDateTime <= end )
              select (int)p.DurationInSeconds ).Sum();
}
return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code per whymatter:

```
        int count;
        using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) )
            {
            count = ( from p in db.Table<TickRecord>()
                      where ( p.TickStartDate >= start && p.TickEndDate <= end )
                      select (int)p.DurationInSeconds ).Sum();
            }
        return count;
```

Thx!